# How to make entityFramework asking me before create db;

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I want to make Entity Framework showing me message : 'There is no database' (if database not exist) and asking me for create db or not;
i use CodeFirst.

Comment: Would your application work if you answered NO to such question? If not, why do you bother about such alert message?

Comment: if i get the message i will configure some settings (server,dbName,dbLocation,Authentication Mode) and finally Create Db;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your 'DbMigrationsConfiguration' class, you should turn off any automatic migrations:

```
public Configuration()
{
   AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
}
```

Now on bootup, it won't do anything other than throw an DBMigrationException when you first access the database.  So, before you access the database, check to see if it exists by using the following:

```
dbContext.Database.Exists();
```

You can then ask your questions about server location, etc, followed by creating the database with:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
migrator.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something built into Entity Framework, nor does it make sense to build it into Entity Framework, because it is so specific to your particular application that whatever you come up with won't be directly usable in any other application.

You can simply configure EF to not automatically create any database. If connecting to the database fails, check if you can connect to the server. If you can connect to the server, check if the database exists. If the database does not exist, offer to create it.